# C# using SQL Connection object for timer function

Tags: c#, timer, database-connection

I'm creating an winforms application.
In which one form is made transparent, This form is used to show some popup message boxes, using a timer this form queries database in each seconds.

Currently I'm using database connection inside using method (here postgres Data Base).

**Method 1**

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class frmCheckStatus: Form
    {
        private void timerCheckStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("My Connection String"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //Database queries
                //Show popup message
                conn.Close();//Forsing to close
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in each seconds this connection object is created and disposed.

**Note : I'm not using this object for any other purpose or inside any forms or methods.**

Is it good to create and use a single connection object global to this class, and use inside timer tick function?, and dispose on form close event

**Method 2**

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class frmCheckStatus: Form
    {
        Private NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("My Connection String");
        private void timerCheckStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Here use conn object for queries.
            conn.Open();
            //Database queries
            //Show popup message
            conn.Close();//Forsing to close
        }
        private void frmCheckStatus_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Which will be better?, considering memory, resource usage, execution time etc. Please give proper reason for your choice of method.

Comment: I'm created a auto closing popup to show last number of entries, "SELECT Count(*) FROM table1", no more complications, and can use a close and Dipose mehod inside a distructor method (~).

Comment: Dont rely on a destructor to close your connection for you, you have no control over when / if it will be called. Its much better to close the connection yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for your connection class ([Here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual)), it would appear that this supports connection pooling. This will mean that connections to the same endpoint (same connection string) will reuse existing connections rather than incurring the overhead of creating new ones.

Im not familiar with your particular connection, but if the behaviour is anything like SQLConnection class for ADO.net, repeatedly creating a new connection to the same connection string should not be particularly expensive (computationally).

As an aside, i would wrap your connection logic in try / finally to ensure it gets closed in the event of an application exception.

Comment: Here POOLING=TRUE in default

Comment: also what about conn.open() inside form constructor (not every timer tick) ? and conn.close() inside destructor

Comment: As a general rule, you want your connection open for the shortest amount of time. There are only a limited number of possible connections, you dont want to be hanging onto one for no reason.

Comment: You can see in documentation "ConnectionLifeTime = 15 seconds in default", i'm querying in each seconds or 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any advantage to instantiating a new connection every time you run a new query.  I know it's done often in code, but there is overhead associated with it, however small.  If you're running multiple queries from the start of the program to the end of the program, I think you should re-use the existing connection object.

If your goal is to make the connection "disappear" from the server (which I wouldn't generally worry about if this program runs on one machine -- if it runs on dozens, that's another story -- look up PgBounce), then that should be just as easily accomplished by turning connection pooling off, and then the `Close()` method would take care of it.

You kind of asked for pros and cons, and while it's not necessarily *harmful* to instantiate the connection within the loop, I can't imagine how it could be better.

For what it's worth, you may want to consider carrying the connection as a property (preferably outside of the form class, since you may want to eventually use it elsewhere).  Something like this:

```
 private NpgsqlConnection _PgConnection;
 public NpgsqlConnection PgConnection
 {
     get
     {
         if (_PgConnection == null)
         {
            NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sb.Host = "hostname.whatever.com";
            sb.Port = 5432;
            sb.UserName = "scott";
            sb.Password = "tiger";
            sb.Database = "postgres";
            sb.Pooling = true;

            _PgConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(sb.ToString());
         }

         if (!_PgConnection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
             _PgConnection.Open();

         return _PgConnection;
     }

     set { _PgConnection = value; }
 }
```

Then, within your form (or wherever you execute your SQL), you can just call the property:

```
NpgSqlCommand cmd = new NpgSqlCommand("select 1", Database.PgConnection);
...
Database.PgConnection.Close();
```

And you don't need to worry if the connection is open or closed, or if it's even been created yet.

The only open question would be if you want that connection to actually disappear on the server, which would be changed by altering the Pooled property.